# Does Jekyll work with Pow?

Tags: jekyll, rack-pow

How do I get [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to work with [Pow](http://pow.cx/)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the [@mipadi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696711/does-jekyll-work-with-pow/6696982#6696982), I learned that [Pow automatically serves static files](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.4) in the `public` directory of your application, so just [configure Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Configuration) to change the directory where Jekyll will write files to from `_site` (the default) to `public`. Since `public` doesn't start with an underscore (`_`), you also have to add it to the list of files & directories to exclude. The relevant parts of my `_config.yaml` look like this:

```
destination: public
exclude: ["CNAME", "Rakefile", "README.md", "public"]
```

Then, just do the usual:

```
cd ~/.pow
ln -s /path/to/myjekyllsite
```

And navigate to http://myjekyllsite.dev/.

[Pow public directory trailing slash issue](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/183): Going to http://myjekyllsite.dev/projects should automatically redirect to http://myjekyllsite.dev/projects/ but didn't.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this to work, even configuring Jekyll  to compile to the 'public' directory. I get 404s or Chrome just uses a search engine to look for myjekyllsite.dev. 

Also, this is made even more messy if you have a Jekyll site that runs  on Github Pages. username.github.com.dev confuses it. You'll have to create an alias when you symlink.

Comment: Edit: Uninstalled pow, reinstalled pow, works fine now. The proverbial jiggling of the handle at work once again.

Comment: I'm justing getting started with Jekyll and Pow, it works for me to use the `destination: public` and then symlink with Pow. Mipadi's link points to the Pow 2.4 Serving Static Files. At first, I had the 404 and that's because I had the `jekyll --server` running, once I stopped jekyll the Pow serving took over and I'm 200!

Comment: After setting `destination: public` in your config.yml make sure to run jekyll build

Answer (score 9):

Here's an approach that doesn't require overriding any of the normal Jekyll defaults:

Install [rack-jekyll](https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll):

```
gem install rack-jekyll
```

Add `config.ru` with the following contents:

```
require "rack/jekyll"
run Rack::Jekyll.new
```

And now symlink your project directory into `~/.pow` as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Pow, but it [looks like](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.4) you could just symlink the output of your Jekyll-generated site into `~/.pow/public`.